# Is it possible to display Canvas in WP7?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, windows-phone-7, canvas

I'm trying to get Internet Explorer Mobile 7 to display Canvas.
I have used ExplorerCanvas and the page works in IE7 (as I understand IE Mobile 7 is based on IE7).

Here is the code:

```
<html> 
<head> 
  <title>Canvas Test</title> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  window.onload = function() { 
    var canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
    var context = canvasElement.getContext("2d"); 
    context.fillStyle = "blue"; 
    context.fillRect(20,20,20,20); 
  }
  </script>
</head> 
<body> 
  <canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"/> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Is it possible to get this to work on WP7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 does not support HTML5 and any possible manual implementation (e.g. through JavaScript) is not guaranteed to work. In your case, you are using the `CANVAS` tag - and it is not supported. IE on Windows Phone 7 is more like IE 7.5 (with features both from IE7 and IE8) - but this is only a subset available on the mobile device. **IE on WP7 != IE on Windows**.

Comment: @Jimmy: In particular Mobile IE 7 does not support VML (or ironically Silverlight) on which ExplorerCanvas relies to do its stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Just stumbled on that article saying WP 7.1 will have a new browser based on IE9, with support for canvas: http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/07/14/building-cross-platform-mobile-applications-with-html5-and-mango.aspx

Comment: The Windows Phone 7 'Mango' update will include a browser that supports HTML5